# iTunes Music player controlling from third party apps ios

Tags: ios, itunes, audio-player

I would like to know whether it is possible to control apple's dedicated music player from my app, so that i can use play, pause, next and previous songs. Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible with the `MPMusicPlayerController`.

From the docs:

> Use an MPMusicPlayerController object, or music player, to play media items from the device iPod library. There are two types of music player:
>
> 1. The application music player plays music locally within your app. It is not aware of the iPod app’s now-playing item, nor does it affect the iPod state.
> 2. The iPod music player employs the built-in iPod app on your behalf. On instantiation, it takes on the current iPod app state, such as the identification of the now-playing item. If a user switches away from your app while music is playing, that music continues to play. The iPod app then has your music player’s most recently-set repeat mode, shuffle mode, playback state, and now-playing item.